# How to recover account on Project Euler?

Tags: account-recovery, project-euler

I've forgotten the password I used years ago and they don't seem to have a password reset feature. Instead, it says:

> If you have forgotten your username and/or password and you have generated an
>   emergency account recovery key then you can use it to recover your account.

But there's no evident way to generate an emergency account recovery key. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

"emergency account recovery key" was generated and sent to you during your registration via your email client

Answer (score 0):

So there is a spot in your projecteuler.net account.
Click on Account -> Generate Key (button)
No it does not actually send an email, it generates a key and a link that includes the key.
If you choose to email these to yourself, or put them in an encrypted file, password safe, etc... then you will be able to recover your account later by utilizing the key you have stored.